# Converting string into date type in PHP

Tags: php, date

```
$a2 = $_POST["e2"] ;
$time = strtotime( ' $a2 ');
$myDate = date ("Y-m-d", $time );
echo $myDate ;
$n = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($myDate)) . " +24 month");
$q = date("Y-m-d", $n);
echo $q ;
```

Output of above is: 1970-01-011972-01-01
e2 was entered as : 24/09/2012
So expected output was: 24/09/2012 24/09/2014
What should I do for this output. Pls help.

Comment: Have you tried to use it `strtotime($a2);` without quotes?

Comment: Single quotes do not extrapolate variables within.

Comment: ya i tried with out quotes but the same output

Comment: Y-m-d doesn't that mean year month day, whereas you want day month year? (probably not the issue, but helpful for layout?)

Answer (score 0):

Date given to [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) separated by slashes must be in the format `m/d/y`. You are passing a date in the format `d/m/y`. Change the separator to `.` or `-`.

> Note:
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your slashes

```
$time = strtotime( ' 24-09-2012 ');
$myDate = date ("Y-m-d", $time );
echo $myDate ;
$n = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($myDate)) . " +24 month");
$q = date("Y-m-d", $n);
echo $q ;
```